# How to implement authorization through Google?

Tags: spring, react-native, google-oauth, expo

I'm developing a mobile app in `Expo` React Native and using `Spring` as a backend. I need to authorizethrough Google.

Expo has a special function `Google.logInAsync (options)` which returns

```
{type: 'success', accessToken, idToken, refreshToken, {... profileInformation}}
```

Now how to use this token with my server?

Comment: Do you want to log in your server after google login?

Answer (score 0):

you need to have a two **additional** field in database

1. `loginType` : google(in your case) / facebook / twitter / normal
2. `accessToken` : save access token in this field you get from  `Google.logInAsync (options)` on registration or first login.

Now whenever registered user logins via google just check login `type == "google"` and `accessToken == "USER_TOKEN"` and you're good to go

Comment: I also did the usual authorization through Spring Security. and all endpoints check this token and give access, I wanted to feed the token from google to Spring Security